# Node.Js data upload to MongoDB - Text file to array to object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to take a txt file that looks like.

1. HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)
2. HCI Revision: 0x23A1
3. LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)
4. LMP Subversion: 0x4176

I'm trying to put said file into Mongodb in JSON format via node. The more i dig in the more i'm losing my mind. I was just introduced to node streams. Any thoughts would go a long way and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use regex or use split on the colon for each of the rows.
For the first one your regular expression could look something like:

```
/HCI Version:.+?(?=\))+\)/g
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split